# Cola sin entradas duplicadas

Tags: c++, contenedores

Estoy tratando de implementar una cola de manera que no se puedan insertar objetos repetidos. Tengo esta implementación que he encontrado pero me da error:

```
    std::queue<punto> q;
    std::set<std::reference_wrapper<punto>> s;
    // to add:

    void add(punto const & x)
    {
        if (s.find(x) == s.end())
        {
            q.push(x);
            s.insert(std::ref(q.back()));  // or "s.emplace(q.back());"
        }
    }
```

El `s.find(x)` me dice ninguna instancia de función sobrecargada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Efectivamente, `std::set` no tiene un método `find` que puedas usar ya que es un contenedor que ya se encuentra indizado (y a diferencia de `std::map` no tiene clave, luego buscar un elemento no tiene sentido).

Sin embargo, si tiene un método `count` que te sirve para tus propósitos:

```
if (s.count(x) == 0)
{
    q.push(x);
    s.insert(std::ref(q.back()));  // or "s.emplace(q.back());"
}
```

Como `set` no admite duplicados, `count` únicamente podría devolver 0 o 1.

Comment: Gracias, es justo lo que necesitaba.